# Change the url using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I just want to change the urls of my website using htaccess. Please tell me if i can change
the url
"www.mysite.com/carbooking" to "www.mysite.com/cars".
"www.mysite.com/avaibletickets" to "www.mysite.com/tickets" and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Redirect` directives from [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect). For example:

```
Redirect /carbooking http://www.mysite.com/cars
```

or rewrite rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^carbooking$ http://anvi.hostoi/cars [L]
```

Comment: i didn't try this before. So please give me the full code. what to insert in my .htaccess file now?

Comment: Just put this one line to your .htaccess file and see whether it's working. You'll need one line per a redirect.

Comment: my code is: 
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

Redirect /flighttickets http://mysite.com/flights
Redirect /holidays-india http://mysite.com/india
Redirect /holidays-world http://mysite.com/world
Redirect /carbooking http://mysite.com/cars
Redirect /busbooking http://mysite.com/buses
Redirect /hotelbooking http://mysite.com/hotels
Redirect /miceenquiry http://mysite.com/mice
Redirect /contactuspage http://mysite.com/support

Comment: You're mixing redirects with rewrite rules. In this case it's better to switch to rewrite rules only. For cars use this after `RewriteEngine on` : `RewriteRule ^/carbooking$ http://anvi.hostoi/cars [L]`

Comment: RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteRule ^/flighttickets$ http://www.mysite.com/flights[L]
RewriteRule ^/holidays-india$ http://www.mysite.com/india[L]
RewriteRule ^/holidays-world$ http://www.mysite.com/world[L]
RewriteRule ^/carbooking$ http://www.mysite.com/cars [L]
RewriteRule ^/busbooking$ http://www.mysite.com/buses[L]
RewriteRule ^/hotelbooking$ http://www.mysite.com/hotels[L]
RewriteRule ^/miceenquiry$ http://www.mysite.com/mice[L]
RewriteRule ^/contactuspage$ http://www.mysite.com/support[L]

Comment: Try to take off `/` in the left part of RewriteRule.
`RewriteRule ^carbooking$ http://anvi.hostoi/cars [L]`

That might work :D

Comment: Please help me to fix this.

Comment: I've tested it on my localhost and `RewriteRule ^carbooking$ http://anvi.hostoi/cars [L]` worked